# Find the value of $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If 
$$x + \frac{1}{x} = 1$$
Then find the value of $p$, where
$$p = x^{4000} + \frac{1}{x^{4000}}.$$

I tried to solve it by squaring the equation.
But by this method , i can get the value of 
$$x^{4096} + \frac{1}{x^{4096}}$$
But not the value of $p$.

How I can solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We know $x + \frac{1}{x} = 1$, so $x^2 + 1 = x,$ or $x^2 -x + 1 = 0.$ Solve for $x,$ and substitute in $p.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

- $$\dfrac{x^2+ 1}{x}=1 \implies x^2-x+1=0 \implies x^3+1=0~~~ \mbox{with $x \neq 1$}$$
- So, $x$ is a complex cube root of $-1$.
- The user *miracle173* points out that we don't have to recall Euler and De-Moivre as just plugging in $x^3=-1$ is sufficient. $$x^{4000}+\dfrac{1}{x^{4000}}=-x-\dfrac 1 x=-1$$

(Thanks for pointing that out, *miracle173*.)

---

- Recall Euler's Form of a complex number and De-Moivre's Theorem

Comment: If these hints are not sufficient, or you have problem executing one or more of them, feel free to ping me here.

Comment: i am not getting it.Can you please explain a little more? Thanks so much.

Comment: To facilitate my writing out some details, it would help me if you can tell me about whether you have evaluated complex cube roots of unity in your class.

Comment: Will it be equal to 1 ? Using the rule $$ w^3 =1 $$ where w is a complex root.

Comment: Well, an equation of degree $3$ has three roots, so what are the other two roots? So, one real root is $1$, there are two complex roots. Have you done some work on these in a class?

Comment: @Kannappan Sampath: it is not necessary "Recall Euler's Form of a complex number and De-Moivre's Theorem". The answer follows immediately if one substitutes $-1$ for $x^3$ in the second equation.

Comment: @miracle173 It's quite possible as I did not work out the details, but you'll still be let with $-x-\frac 1 x$ and then, you can take conjugate and multiply. Maybe, I'll add this in if this is what you're saying.

Comment: @Kannappan Sampath: but $-x-1/x=-(x+1/x)$ an d the value of $x+1/x$ is known by the initial equation

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah, I am sorry. I did not take a look. So, the solution gets even more slick. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @miracle173 I have edited to add your point. How does it look? (Thanks for telling anyway.)